# How can I reverse mouse scrolling across all applications?

Tags: gnome, mouse, xinput

I use two mice, but I don't like the scroll direction on the left-hand one so I used `xinput` to swap scroll-up and scroll-down specifically on that mouse (`xinput set-button-map "Primax Kensington Eagle Trackball" 2 1 3 5 4 8 9` to be exact). Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be respected in all applications, in particular I'm seeing that `Konsole` scrolls the same way regardless of `xinput` settings (though I've come across a couple of other ones too, such as the `Test Your Settings` dialogue in the Gnome mouse settings). Is there a better way I can use that will reverse the scroll direction *for that mouse only* across all applications? I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.